# Using Python for force strength

Tags: python, force-fields

I am trying to program real data into my animation. In order to do so I need to address force. I do not have much experience programming and was wondering if someone could direct me and explain how to directly address magnetic force and its strength.

Comment: Can you elaborate?  As in if you put a magnetic force field onto the default cube, and hover over the strength field, you see `bpy.data.objects["Cube"].fields.strength` ??

Comment: Yes but in what ways can I manipulate this in order to make a for loop